# Creating variables and calculating the difference between these variables and selected variable - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I've got this data frame:

```
ID  Date        X   123_P   456_P   789_P   choice
A   07/16/2019  .   1.5     1.8     1.6     123
A   07/17/2019  .   2.0     2.1     4.5     789
A   07/18/2019  .   3.0     3.2     NaN     0
A   07/19/2019  .   2.1     2.2     4.5     456
B   07/16/2019  .   1.5     1.8     1.6     789
B   07/17/2019  .   2.0     2.1     4.5     0
B   07/18/2019  .   3.0     3.2     NaN     123
```

I want to create new variables: 123_PD, 456_PD, 789_PD (I have much more variables than this example, so it shouldn't be done manually).

The new variables will indicate the differences between 123_P, 456_P, 789_P variables and the same variables from the previous row, **considering the previous choice**.

I mean, if the choice from the previous row was "123", so the differences between these variables will refer to value in "123_P" from the previous row.

Notes:

- Value of 0 means there is no choice, so the differences will refer to the last choice for this ID.
- It should be done for each ID separately.

Expected result:

```
ID  Date        X   123_P   456_P   789_P   choice  123_PD  456_PD  789_PD
A   07/16/2019  .   1.5     1.8     1.6     123     0       0       0
A   07/17/2019  .   2.0     2.1     4.5     789     0.5     0.6     3.0
A   07/18/2019  .   3.0     3.2     NaN     0       -1.5    -1.3    NaN
A   07/19/2019  .   2.1     2.2     4.5     456     -2.4    -2.3    0
B   07/16/2019  .   1.5     1.8     1.6     789     0       0       0
B   07/17/2019  .   2.0     2.1     4.5     0       0.4     0.5     2.9
B   07/18/2019  .   3.0     3.2     NaN     123     1.4     1.6     NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create helper DataFrame with new column `0_P` for filled missing values and change `choice` values for match columns names:

```
df1 = (df.join(pd.DataFrame({'0_P':np.nan}, index=df.index))
         .assign(choice = df['choice'].astype(str) + '_P'))

print (df1)
  ID        Date  X  123_P  456_P  789_P choice  0_P
0  A  07/16/2019  .    1.5    1.8    1.6  123_P  NaN
1  A  07/17/2019  .    2.0    2.1    4.5  789_P  NaN
2  A  07/18/2019  .    3.0    3.2    NaN    0_P  NaN
3  A  07/19/2019  .    2.1    2.2    4.5  456_P  NaN
4  B  07/16/2019  .    1.5    1.8    1.6  789_P  NaN
5  B  07/17/2019  .    2.0    2.1    4.5    0_P  NaN
6  B  07/18/2019  .    3.0    3.2    NaN  123_P  NaN
```

Then use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) for values to array, convert to `Series`, [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and forward filling missing values per groups in lambda function:

```
s = (pd.Series(df1.lookup(df1.index, df1['choice']), index=df.index)
       .groupby(df['ID'])
       .apply(lambda x: x.shift().ffill()))
print (s)
0    NaN
1    1.5
2    4.5
3    4.5
4    NaN
5    1.6
6    1.6
dtype: float64
```

Then select necessary columns, subtract by [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html), [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and last set rows to `0` by duplicated `ID` column:

```
df2 = df.iloc[:, -4:-1].sub(s, axis=0).add_suffix('D')
df2.loc[~df1['ID'].duplicated(), :] = 0
print (df2)
   123_PD  456_PD  789_PD
0     0.0     0.0     0.0
1     0.5     0.6     3.0
2    -1.5    -1.3     NaN
3    -2.4    -2.3     0.0
4     0.0     0.0     0.0
5     0.4     0.5     2.9
6     1.4     1.6     NaN

df = df.join(df2)
print (df)
  ID        Date  X  123_P  456_P  789_P  choice  123_PD  456_PD  789_PD
0  A  07/16/2019  .    1.5    1.8    1.6     123     0.0     0.0     0.0
1  A  07/17/2019  .    2.0    2.1    4.5     789     0.5     0.6     3.0
2  A  07/18/2019  .    3.0    3.2    NaN       0    -1.5    -1.3     NaN
3  A  07/19/2019  .    2.1    2.2    4.5     456    -2.4    -2.3     0.0
4  B  07/16/2019  .    1.5    1.8    1.6     789     0.0     0.0     0.0
5  B  07/17/2019  .    2.0    2.1    4.5       0     0.4     0.5     2.9
6  B  07/18/2019  .    3.0    3.2    NaN     123     1.4     1.6     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the needful:

```
df[['123_PD', '456_PD', '789_PD']] = df[['123_P', '456_P', '789_P']] - df[['123_P', '456_P', '789_P']].shift(1) 

df['123_PD'].iloc[0] = 0
df['456_PD'].iloc[0] = 0
df['789_PD'].iloc[0] = 0
```

Comment: No, it's not. Because you don't account for the last choice, and not for the IDs.